# Thermocycle library and OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

I want to load Thermocycle library by OpenModelica connect edition. But I get a message "The file was not encoded in UTF-8"

To fix this problem I should: "add a file package.encoding at the top-level." But I don't understand what must I do? What is the file which called "package.encoding", what should this file consist from? Where should I insert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all. **"add a file package.encoding at the top-level."**

Put the file where your library's package.mo is located.
The file must contain the name of encoding used by the library.

Note that you can also use OMEdit's encoding conversion feature. **File->Open/Convert Modelica File(s) With Encoding**

Comment: There are many problems in simulation of examples inside the Thermocycle library. I can't simulate these examples. Do you have it in ThermoCycle.Examples.Simulations.step_by_step.ORC_245fa?

Comment: What kind of problems? Post the errors, perhaps someone can help you.

Comment: Yes, of course, please see the attached link with a picture https://yadi.sk/i/4AwMJFjrcFSJd